# How do I retrieve specific child(s) from a firebase database node instead of the snapshot of everything in the node?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
I know how to obtain all the child in the node using the reference below.

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Node').orderByKey();
dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot)
}
```

Now what I can't figure out is how do I obtain only specific child from the database. How do I simultaneously retrieve just `[1001,1004,1005]`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The only way in which you can get data from a Firebase dababase is using the `snapshot`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand that, can I get specific snapshot of selected child(s) instead of the snapshot of everything ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to go a step down in your three and use `snapshot` at that particular child.

Comment: what if I have an array of multiple child(s) for example [1002,1004,1001], how do I reference that?

Comment: There is no array there, there are always pairs of key and values. In this way Firebase is structured. So, to get all those childrens you need to use `snapshot` as it appears in your code. This is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change the structure to became like this :

```
---Node :
   --- 1001 : true
   --- 1002 : true
   --- 1003 : true
   --- 1004 : true
   --- 1005 : true
```

Next in your code :

```
var arrResult = [];
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Node').orderByKey();
dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
       console.log(childSnapshot.key);
       arrResult.push(childSnapshot.key);
    });

    console.log(arrResult);
}
```

If you want to find specific targets, then you just need to compare between target array and result array