# How can I find a match of multiple children in firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to find a way to retrieve specific sets of child(s) from a firebase database node, but from what I found out it can't be done based on my research and answer to this question. [How do I retrieve specific child(s) from a firebase database node instead of the snapshot of everything in the node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332747/how-do-i-retrieve-specific-childs-from-a-firebase-database-node-instead-of-the/45332800?noredirect=1#comment77628116_45332800)

I think a workaround for this could be if I reference each alerted ID in the array and then obtain their snapshots consecutively. Hence, I have this file reader that obtains ID values from a CSV file and separate them and then alert each ID value.

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {

  var trnsarray = reader.result.split(/\s+/).splice(1).join(', ');

  var newarray = trnsarray.split(',').map(parseFloat);

  for (var i=0; i < newarray.length; i++) {

    alert(newarray[i]);

  }
```

Instead alerting each ID I want it to get a snapshot of each ID in `newarray`. I tried the function below but it does not read the ID at all.

```
 var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Node').(newarray[i]);
 dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot)
  }
```

How can I obtain a snapshot value of each ID in `newarray` consecutively? How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a **child** in your code :

```
.(newarray[i]);
```

Try this :

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Node');

for (var i=0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
    dbRef.child(newarray[i]).on('value', snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, we can get snapshot children, we can utilize this feature with code like this:

```
var trnsarray = reader.result.split(/\s+/).splice(1).join(', ');
var beforearray = trnsarray.split(',').map(parseFloat);
var newarray = [];
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Node').orderByKey();
dbRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
       console.log(childSnapshot.key);
       if(beforearray.includes(childSnapshot.key)){ 
          console.log(childSnapshot.key + ' : ' + childSnapshot.val());
          //put your code here
          newarray.push(childSnapshot.key);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: newarray contains many unique IDs i.e. 100002, 140502, 400562. So I want to run each of those IDs against  childSnapshot.key and return the snapshot for the matching ID. This code    if(newarray.includes(childSnapshot.key))  does not successfully does that. How can I correct it?

Comment: @Ola i've edited my answer. If i'm not mistake, you want to get id that has inserted in firebase database right?

Comment: I pretty much want to find 100002, 140502 and 400562 in the firebase database.